# что это строка делает?

Tags: c#

почему somemethod ничего не возвращает ?
можете объяснить как работает Select

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {    
            List<int> listInt = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            listInt.Select(async i => await SomeMethod(i));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task SomeMethod(int i)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            });
        }
```

Comment: Почему ничего? Он возвращает таск

Comment: В вашем случае ничего не происходит, тип как Select не отработает, пока коллекция не будет материализована. Это ж ленивые вычисления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listInt.ForEach(async i => await SomeMethod(i));
```

если ты хочешь вызвать данный метод на каждый элемент листа, то используй такую конструкцию
а конструкция с Select проецирует каждый элемент в новую форму, используется делегат Func(который возвращает какое-либо значение), а в конструкция ForEach делегат Action(не возвращает значение)